# Maximum matching in a tree

Tags: graph-theory, dynamic-programming

We were asked to suggest a dynamic program algorithm to Find maximum matching in a tree in linear time, $O(|V|+|E|)$.

I have no clue how to start.
any Ideas?

Comment: Is this a weighted tree? Or does the maximum matching just involve covering the most vertices?

Comment: not a weighted tree, need to find maximum coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Denote by $A(v,\text{True})$ the maximal matching in the sub-tree where $v$ is its root, where edges with one endpoint equal to $v$ are allowed.

Denote by $A(v,\text{False})$ the maximal matching in the sub-tree where $v$ is its root, where edges with one endpoint equal to $v$ are 
**not** allowed.

Feel free to ask for some clarifications if this does not help you :)

Comment: @paulinho This construction will also work for weighted trees. I thought it might interest you.